# Read from and Write into same excel Workbook

Tags: excel, perl

Hi I want to read data from Excel Worksheet and write into the another Sheet of same workbook using perl.

I tried using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser. But it is mentioned that its undergoing restructuring. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: [`Win32::OLE`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE)

Comment: Any other because I will be running the script from linux environment.

Comment: There is no way to edit a spreadsheet in-place rather than read a spreadsheet and create a new one, except by using the Excel process itself such as that. It may be possible to use LibreOffice the same way but I don't think there is such an advanced solution for that.